# pydev not in Eclipse perspecitive list

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am having the apparently common problem of PyDev not showing up in the perspective list after install. After trying all the various suggested solutions without success, I don't know what to do next and need some help. I installed PyDev version 5 on Eclipse version 4.2.2 with JRE 1.8.0_73-b02. TIA.

Comment: Did you try making a new project? Does it show you PyDev in the 'Select a wizard' window?

Comment: Yes. I do not see it anywhere except About>Installation Details>Installed Software.

Comment: I wound up installing Aptana Studio 3 which has PyDev in it and that worked. The implication is that there is something wrong with the vanilla PyDev installer. I have a lot of extra stuff I don't need but at least it works now.

Comment: Rats!! Back to square one. Aptana's version of PyDev is buggy. I need to get the real PyDev working.

Comment: Am I the only one that cannot get PyDev to work?

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed by editing the eclipse.ini to use java-8

this line ->
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin

to this ->
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin

I guess there is some other ways too to update eclipse configuration with java versions.